# My Harley Davidson's fuel gauge has become very erratic over the last week

Tags: maintenance, gauges, harley-davidson

The fuel gauge on my 2011 Harley Davidson Ultra Limited used to move a little under heavy braking or acceleration, but broadly speaking was accurate-ish. The bike has done 20000 miles, and maintained very well - I don't take it off road much, but I do ride all year round so it sees its fair share of ice and snow.

Over the last week, it has taken to moving by about half the gauge when accelerating or braking, and moves around a lot when I change gears.

I know the float in the tank moves a lot, so some sort of damping is generally used, but what kind would it be, and why would it fail.

Answer (score 2):

An electronic solution to the engineering problem of damping might be easier than complicating the mechanical sensor inside the fuel tank.

Indeed this [Harley-Davidson forum](https://www.harley-davidsonforums.com/threads/fuel-gauge.91506/) has:

> **fuel gauge**
>
> Q. . . one day my fuel gauge started bouncing around. Obviously the float bounces up and down when the bike is moving but now it is reflected in the fuel gauge.
>
> A. . . the dampening capacitors **in the gauge** are shot and the gauge needs to be replaced.

That thread also advises how to test the gauge.